# Try another nginx server if not found

Tags: nginx

we’re in a middle of migrating our nginx to another one that is running under docker container (until we finish the migration it’s using a virtual network)

How can I redirect all request to not founded `server` (block) to the another nginx instance?

For example if I open the browser on `http://some.thing.com` (DNS route to my server) and my nginx server doesn’t found that `server` (block) than it should try another nginx server for that

---

Using 404 on each `server` block isn’t a solution cause we have many of them

Comment: Try reverse proxying the default virtual host (the `server` block which has the `listen 80 default_server` or similar https clause).

Comment: Something like `error_page 404 = @myownredirect;` and `location @myownredirect { proxy_pass … }`?